# Javascript regex replace single slash in to double slash?

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

Javascript regex replace single slash into double slash not for replace double slash in a string?

```
var tempPath ="//DocumentImages//Invoices//USD//20130425//I27566554 Page- 1.tif&//hercimg/IMAGES/2008/20130411/16192144/16192144-10003.tif&";
```

Here replace all single slash in to double (//) not to all double slash.

like `//DocumentImages//Invoices//USD//20130425//I27566554 Page- 1.tif&//hercimg//IMAGES//2008//20130411//16192144//16192144-10003.tif&`

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes.
var tempPath ="//DocumentImages//Invoices//USD//20130425//I27566554 Page- 1.tif&//hercimg/IMAGES/2008/20130411/16192144/16192144-10003.tif&";
image = tempPath.replace(/\//g,"\/\/");
and i get.
////DocumentImages////Invoices////USD////20130425////I27566554 Page- 1.tif&////hercimg//IMAGES//2008//20130411//16192144//16192144-10003.tif&

Comment: I made it now...
I am new to stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourString.replace(/([^\/])\/([^\/])/g,"$1//$2")
```

Comment: @ramesh, please check my updated answer. Sorry, I did not check that the previous one replaced also the 2 chars on the side

Comment: Yes ...
I noticed after sometime...
Thank You again... :)

Answer (score 1):

This would work *assuming* your string does not also end in a `/`

```
yourString.replace(/\/[^\/]/g,"//")
```

- `/stuff/` is just JavaScript regex literal notation
- `\/` is an escaped "/"
- `[^\/]` is anything *but* a "/" (again, with escaping)
- the "g" on the regex literal means "replace all matches and not just the first"

which we replace for "//" which is what you want.

replace accepts a string and returns a new string with the value changed without changing the original.

#### [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mc2gj/)

Comment: I expect
//DocumentImages//Invoices//USD//20130425//I27566554 Page- 1.tif&//hercimg//IMAGES//2008//20130411//16192144//16192144-10003.tif&

Not this 
///ocumentImages///nvoices///SD///0130425///27566554 Page- 1.tif&///ercimg//MAGES//008//0130411//6192144//6192144-10003.tif&

Answer (score 0):

Could be also helpful:

```
var s = "http://www.some-url.com//path//to";
var res = s.replace(/(https?:\/\/)|(\/)+/g, "$1$2");
```