# How to allow forward slash in javascript Regex?

Tags: jquery, regex

Here, I have blocked to type special characters for **all input type** in my mobile browser.
But it will allow all alphabets and numbers.

My requirement is to allow the users to type only **/** (forward slash) for **particular field** (for example: Date field).

Is it possible in a simple way?

Instead of assigning class name for all input types except for the particular field which I need / (forward slash)?

```
   $(document).on('keypress','input', function(event){  
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

**Note:** I need to allow forward slash to particular class instead of doing all input fields.

Simple: I need to block special characters for all input fields expect the particular class (let's say )

I'm not asking for the solution with the same regex function. I need separate click event to allow only slash for the particular class 'someclassname'

Comment: Yes, you need to `escape` it with \:   `\/`

Comment: Use reverse slash to escape chars. `\/` outputs `/`.

Comment: But that will applicable to all input fields right? I need to allow forward slash to particular class instead of doing all input fields

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript regex replace single slash in to double slash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711578/javascript-regex-replace-single-slash-in-to-double-slash)

Comment: @edi9999: can't understand my question? I m not asking for the solution with the same regex function. I need to allow slash for the particular class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether focused input has a class of your date input or its type is date using the function `is`. Then you can combine another `regexp` with your previous expression. Code:

```
$(document).on('keypress','input', function(event){
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    if($("input:focused").is(".classname"))
    {
        regex = new RegExp(regex.source + "|\/");
    }
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

P.S. I am not 100% sure about the code of combining of 2 regexps, just wrote by memory. If doesnt work you can simply add another check, if a string equals to `/`.

Comment: Changed ur code little bit. But it allows forward slash to all elements which has focus....how to resolve this problem? but i gave only classname for the particular field\

Comment: Try to change the condition to: `$("#form-id-if-there-is-one input.class-name:focus").length > 0`

Comment: couldn't get you @zazu

Comment: change the condition inside the first `if` to: `if($("#form-id-if-there-is-one input.class-name:focus").length > 0) { regex = new RegExp(regex.source + "|\/"); }`

Comment: u mean like this?adding if condition        $("#formid input .classname:focus").length > 0

Answer (score 4):

You can add the / into your regex as the following code:

```
 new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+$");
```

Comment: Or, simplier, `^[\w|\d|\/]+$`. I'd suggest OP to use HTML5's `data` attributes to mark the "special (date?) inputs", for example `<input data-type="date" />` or simply `<input data-date/>`.

Comment: Add starting ^ and trailing $, I missed them in the original comment :) and I think g modifier is useless here...

Comment: `^[\w|\d|\/]+$` is not a correctly written regex, since you are using `[]` like `()`. What you suggest can be written as `^[\w\d\/]+$` which means *1 or more alphanumeric and digit characters with `_` and `/` from start to end*. So, it is not the same as `^[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+$` as it also allows `_`.

Comment: @Jack: inside a character class the pipe `|` has no special meaning, it is a literal character and doesn't mean "OR"

Comment: I didn't know `_` is considered a normal character included in `\w`. `^[\da-zA-Z\/]+$` should be fine then :) ... or even `^[\w\/][^_]+$`. Regex ways are infinite :P

Comment: I'm not asking for the solution with the same regex function. I need separate click event to allow only slash for the particular class 'someclassname'

Answer (score 1):

To switch between the two regexes, I'd use this:

```
var regex = $(this).data('date') ? /^[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+$/ : /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

Adding `data-date` to date inputs, like:

```
<input data-date placeholder="I allow slashes" />
<input placeholder="No slashes here" />
```